# How do I force to open a specific activity after a user set the alarm?

Tags: nativescript-vue

I'm trying to make dose schedule app that when the user set the alarm the app shows a page to check if the user takes a medicine or not. and the user should choose snooze or done with swiping ("done" to the left, "snooze" to the right).
I want the app gets opened automatically from the background on time.

I've already tried "[nativescript-local-notification](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications)", but this one, the user must press the notification to open or enter the app and read "[nativescript background service](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript)" but it seems to be the same as I've tried.

Could you tell me the way or give me some example to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by myself. I put the solution that might be helped someone like me.

First you have set an alarm.

alarm.helper.js

```
import * as AlarmReceiver from '@/services/AlarmReceiver' // Do not remove

export const setAlarm = data => {
  const ad = utils.ad
  const context = ad.getApplicationContext()
  const alarmManager = application.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
  const intent = new android.content.Intent(context, io.nerdrun.AlarmReceiver.class)

  const { id, time, title, name } = data

  // set up alarm
  intent.putExtra('id', id)
  intent.putExtra('title', title)
  intent.putExtra('name', name)
  intent.putExtra('time', time.toString())

  const pendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
  alarmManager.setExact(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTime(), pendingIntent)
  console.log('registered alarm')
}
```

Extends AlarmReceiver on Android.

AlarmReceiver.js

```
export const AlarmReceiver = android.content.BroadcastReceiver.extend('io.nerdrun.AlarmReceiver', {
  init: function() {
    console.log('init receiver')
  },
  onReceive: function(context, intent) {
    console.log('You got the receiver man!!')
    const activityIntent = new android.content.Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class)
    const id = intent.getExtras().getInt('id')
    const title = intent.getExtras().getString('title')
    const name = intent.getExtras().getString('name')
    const time = intent.getExtras().getString('time')      

    activityIntent.putExtra('id', id)
    activityIntent.putExtra('title', title)
    activityIntent.putExtra('name', name)
    activityIntent.putExtra('time', time)
    activityIntent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    context.startActivity(activityIntent)
  }
})
```

register receiver to your manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="io.nerdrun.AlarmReceiver" />
```

Of course, you can extend Activity on android into your project, but I haven't implemented it.

After the receiver worked it would navigate to Main Activity, you might control whatever you want in app.js below:

app.js

```
application.on(application.resumeEvent, args => {
  if(args.android) {
    console.log('resume succeed!!!')
    const android = args.android
    const intent = android.getIntent()
    const extras = intent.getExtras()
    if(extras) {
      const id = extras.getInt('id')
      const title = extras.getString('title')
      const name = extras.getString('name')
      const time = extras.getString('time')
      Vue.prototype.$store = store
      Vue.prototype.$navigateTo(routes.home, { clearHistory: true, props: props })
      }
    }
  }
})
```